Is it possible to configure EF and SQL Server to use with JOB Queue in FastEndpoints
Was trying to use Job Queue background scheduled task with FastEndpoint it seems ok with SQlite and LiteDb but could not quick get it working with EF and  SQL Server, is there any sample code I can have a look?
Tried  to use EF and SQL Server but EF did not recognize the JOBRecord entity which is inherited from IJobStorageRecord

the FE documentation links to this example project.

Thanks Dj, I am guessing it uses SQLite instead of Sql Server

you can change this line to .UseSqlServer(...) and that should be it.

Thanks Dj, I have tried it but could not get it working

@GholamrezaFathpour Could you post your code ? And what errors are you getting?
